# Excel formula SUMIFS with dynamic SUMRANGE

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I cannot figure out how to use a variable range in SUMIFS. Hope someone can help.

This is the formula:

```
=SUMIFS($G$52:$G$122;$D$52:$D$122;$C11;$E$52:$E$122;$D11)
```

Or when using a table:

```
=SUMIFS(Details[Percentage];Details[Function];$C11;Details[Reason];$D11)
```

The sum range `G52:G122` should be variable depending on numeric input.
Input 1 (January) is range `J52:J122`, input 2 (February) is range is `K52:K122`, input 3 (March) is range `L52:L122`, etc

Is this possible and if so, how?

I tried to use `INDEX()`, `MATCH()`, `OFFSET()` but just could not get it right.

Thank you.

The formula is in column Used and now refers to %(G) in the next table. It should refer to 1 of the columns January to December, dependig on numeric input (1 to 12).

[image: SUMIFSKH]

Comment: All of those that you mentioned (`INDEX()+MATCH()` or `OFFSET()`) should work. However, `OFFSET()` is a volatile function and `INDEX()+MATCH()` can often be written in a cleaner and more straight forward fashion with `XLOOKUP()`. Try the latter and if it doesn't work, please share how exactly you tried to implement it, possibly with a data example.

Comment: Tnx Dattel. As said, I get lost, probably not using INDEX and MATCH right. If someone can give an example how to use it properly, that would be much appreciated. Never used XLOOKUP before but can try this as well.

Comment: Please _show_ us the formula you tried

Comment: Can I assume that your data is formatted something like in this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sSX4.png)? I.e. you have columns for each month adjacent to one another? That's the kind of examples you should provide in the question so that someone can provide you with a solution

Comment: The `SUMIFS` formula for the table is just fine. The issue that you're encountering may be due to the percentages that you are summing up and due to the format (`General`) of the cell where you have the formula. so the result may always be 0. But you haven't told us what your issue actually is.

Comment: As a new user I am not allowed to show screenshots but @DattelKlauber it looks like the one you shared except for the Index row.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I dont understand what you mean, The formula I use is =SUMIFS($G$52:$G$122;$D$52:$D$122;$C11;$E$52:$E$122;$D11) but this is not dynamic.

Comment: You said you tried using INDEX MATCH, show us your attempt. Also, you can upload images to http:imgur.com and link to them. Someone with enough reputation will likely embed the image for you

Comment: I tried. As it was not succesfull I deleted it.

Comment: OP wants a "column selector" for the sum reference in the `SUMIFS` function. Something like `SUMIFS(INDEX(J52:R112,0,MATCH("January",...` But instead of spelling out January, OP wants an index [1,12].  If not provided by someone in the meantime, Ican put together an example tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested `FILTER` or `INDEX` function to pick column:

specify column by index:
`=SUMIFS(INDEX($G$52:$R$122;0;<col_number>);$D$52:$D$122;$C11;$E$52:$E$122;$D11)`

specify column by name:
`=SUMIFS(FILTER($G$52:$R$122;$G$51:$R$51=<col_name>);$D$52:$D$122;$C11;$E$52:$E$122;$D11)`

Comment: Thanks! I used the INDEX option, changed the range R:G into J:U and use a variable fro col_number.
It works perfect!!!